# Is there a way in Java to get the line number using the jsonpointer from a json file

Tags: java, json, objectmapper, jsonpointer

I have a case wherein I have the jsonpointer and the swagger json file. I need to get the line number to which the jsonpointer is pointing to.

Is there a way to do so, I used ObjectMapper, I get the jsonNode, I also saw in the the code, the JsonParser has the information about the line number when the json file is parsed, I there a way to get the line number for each ObjectNode, or just pass the jsonPointer and get the line number.

Below is the code:

```
public class JsonPointerUtil {
static ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
private JsonNode jsonNode;

public JsonPointerUtil(File json) throws IOException {
    jsonNode = com.xyz.util.JsonPointerUtil.om.readTree(json);
}

public String getJsonBlockForPointer(String jsonPtr) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(jsonPtr))
        return null;
    JsonNode at = jsonNode.at(jsonPtr);
    return at.toString();
}
```

}

So in getJsonBlockForPointer method using the pointer I get the json node, The json node is the exact json block pointed by the pointer, I need the line number also of the pointed json block, Is there a way I can get that.

My requirement is, the line number is used by UI side code, there are multiple UI apps which call the same backend service, On UI side, the jsonPointer library gives me all the information (line,col no, agiainst each jsonPointer), but as there are multiple UI apps consuming the same service, I want to send all theinfo from backend.

Comment: Please provide some code which you have done so far and update your question.

Comment: If you have any specific requirement for line number in json, than you should add additional attribute to your object rather count by pointer

Comment: I have updated the question with code + requirment.

Comment: Hi @KuldeepJadhav, were you able to find solution to your question above? If yes, please help with the solution,  as i am trapped in this for almost 3 weeks now. Help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

posting after long time, we ultimately ended up using javascript only, we called the javascript from java and passing the relevant details.

we basically used

```
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
            long start = new Date().getTime();
            Gson gson=new Gson();
            parse = inv.invokeFunction("getLineNumbers", jsonPointers, swaggerAsString);
```

called the javascript file from java.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).